# Google Sheets - Looking for script that auto capitalizes all cells in a specified column

Tags: google-sheets, google-apps-script

Looking around, I found different things, but I never found the spot where you could specify the range, and I'm not familiar with this script.

Can someone please show me a script for this? For example, all I need it to do is automatically capitalize every cell in column C.

The below block of code seems to  be what I'm looking  for, but I don't see where it specifies the column. I also don't know if this is the right code because there's many different ones that I found, some with long code and some short like this. It looks like it converts the whole sheet to uppercase, which isn't what I want to do - just a specified column.

```
function onEdit(e) {
  if (typeof e.value != 'object') {
    e.range.setValue(e.value.toUpperCase());
  }
}
```

Comment: Welcome.  "with this script" What script is that? By the other side, please follow the [tour] and checkout [ask].

Comment: This would be a script for google sheets, that auto capitalizes all cells within a specified column.

I apologize, I'm not sure how else to answer the question or describe my question

Comment: I understood that you already found a script. I apologize for the misunderstanding. By the other hand, the question needs more details about your search/research efforts as it's suggested in [ask].

Comment: Ohh, I understand now, thank you. 

Well there are some different ones floating around, some really long and some really short. I don't really know the differences

Alrighty I went ahead and updated my OP, I don't know how to add a code block in comments here. Hopefully that helps

Answer (score 0):

The code included in the question doesn't specifies the column.

Try this

```
function onEdit(e) {
  if (typeof e.value != 'object' && e.range.columnStart === 1) {
    e.range.setValue(e.value.toUpperCase());
  }
}
```

Please note that I added `&& e.range.columnStart === 1` . This makes that only values entered in Column A are changed to upper case.